# How to pad out values line by line while mainting overall record length in a Unix Shell script ksh

Tags: shell, unix, sed

```
IFS=$'\n'
while read -r line
do  
--header/trailer record
   if echo ${line} | grep -e '000000000000000' -e '999999999999999' >/dev/null 2>&1
   then
      echo ${line} >> outfile.01.DAT.sampleNEW
   elif echo ${line} | grep '+0' >/dev/null 2>&1
   then
      echo ${line} |  sed -e  's/+/+00000000/; s/        X/X/'       >> outfile.01.DAT.sampleNEW
   else
      echo ${line} |  sed -e  's/-/-00000000/; s/        X/X/'       >> outfile.01.DAT.sampleNEW
   fi
done < Inputfile.01.DAT
```

I have a large file that I need to pad out the amount fields (signed) but retain the overall record length so have to remove some filler spaces at the end (each line ends with X). The file has a header/trailer that does not need to change. I have come up with a way but it is very slow when using a large input file. I am sure the use of grep here is not good.

Sample records. end with X - Overall length 107 bytes

```
000000000000000PPPPPPPPP Information INV TRANSACTION   0120160505201605052154HI203.SEQ  01                X
000000000000001PPPPP14PA    000YYYYYY488 -0001235.2520150319                                              X
000000000000002PPPMS  PA    000RRRRR4539 +0008285.0020160301                                              X
000000000000003PPPP506      000TTTTTT605 -0000225.0020150608                                              X
9999999999999990000000000000439.940000000079802782.180000005                                              X
```

Comment: Comments in shell scripts start with `#`, not `--`; presumably, the `--header/trailer record` is not a command invocation?

Comment: Shell scripts are indeed pretty slow for big jobs.  Why don't you try a C program or perhaps a PHP, Python, or Perl script?

Comment: You preserve input spacing by enclosing the variable in double quotes: `echo "${line}" | sed …`.  Is that the whole problem?  No; speed is a problem.  You should be invoking `sed` once to do all the processing; there's no need for the loop, or running `grep` and `sed` for each line.  That is slow.  Just combine everything into a single `sed` script.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Whatever is is you are trying to do can be done concisely, efficiently, and portably with a small awk script but you'll have to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output for us to be able to help you. Also, read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) if you're interested in knowing why your script is so slow and it'll help you understand some of the other issues with it.

Comment: I did try a variety methods -- this was slightly faster ..

Comment: Please edit your question so it is legible! You need to put 4 spaces at the start of each line of your data. Then, when your input data is legible, please show what the corresponding output data should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want something like this, but it is very hard to tell given the way you have presented your question:

```
awk '
   /000000000000000/ || /999999999999999/ {print;next}
   /\+0/ {sub(/\+0/,"+00000000"); sub(/        X/,'X'); print; next}
   /\-0/ {sub(/\-0/,"-00000000"); sub(/        X/,'X'); print; next}
' Inputfile.01.DAT
```

That says... *"if the line contains a string of 15 zeroes or 15 nines, print it and move to the next line. If the line contains `+0`, replace it with `+00000000` and remove 8 spaces before the final `X`, then print. Likewise for `-0`."*

You could also maybe use Perl, and do something like this:

```
perl -nle '/0{15}|9{15}/ && print; s/([+-])0/$1\0000000000/ && s/      X/X/ && print' Inputfile.01.DAT
```

Comment: Thanks this works so much better than using a shell loop and using read. I read the article suggested by Ed. Is there a way to format this using sed or is awk the best option?

Comment: I guess you could do it with `sed` but it will probably be harder to write/read and no faster, so I would say if the `awk` works and is very readable, go with that...